# C, Contiki rime, transferring a struct

Tags: c, struct, contiki

I have defined a structure

```
typedef struct {
 unsigned short a;
 unsigned short b;
} my_struct;
```

The sending node creates a struct
and transfers it using

```
my_struct my;
packetbuf_copyfrom((void *)&my, sizeof(data_struct));
```

The receiving node accesses the data via

```
my_struct *my;
my = packetbuf_dataptr();
```

So far so good. By when trying to access the members a or b of the struct

```
printf("%u", my.a);
```

I get:

> "error: request for member 'a' in something not a structure or union."

If I transfer a simple string and access it everything is fine.

Comment: Use `printf("%hu", my->a);` as `my_struct.a` is a `unsigned short`, not `unsigned int`, and `my` is a `my_struct *`, not a `my_struct`.

Comment: @EOF: %hu is not supported by msp430-libc (a 16-bit system). Simply %u is just fine.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the my->a part. it works now. Thank your very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access members of a structure, through a structure pointer we have to use arrow operator -> (formed by hyphen and a greater than symbol).

To access your member **a** use

```
printf("%u", my->a);
or
printf("%u", (*my).a);
```